# Windows 10 version 1703 fails to install but recent versions install correctly on a laptop. Using rufus and a bootable usb

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-installation, bootable-media

So, I have a lenovo y530 laptop. I use rufus to download windows 10 iso and do a clean install with bootable usb. I can successfully install recent windows versions like from 1909.

If I try to install the 1703 version, it will go this way : First part of the installation goes well. Then the pc restarts. Then it's when it gets stuck with the spinning dots for hours.

Now the weird part is that it did work once. I don't know why, but since then It won't work again. Nothing has changed.

Does it mean that it randomly works and I just have to try a sufficient amount of times to get it working again ? Or is there a reason behind why it worked once but won't work again ?

As later windows 10 versions work always fine, I guessed it could be a compatibility issue with the motherboard or the bios. Since the laptop was released like 1 year after windows 10 1703 release.

Thanks for your help, my goal is to understand why it doesn't work and how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the laptop was released like 1 year after windows 10 1703
> release.

It is not likely a Windows compatibility issue per se,  but for individual machines, Microsoft enforces up to date Windows.

So I expect what you are finding is that the machine is updating itself (and then will continue to keep updating).

Individual machines (different than corporate LTSC) will update.

If there is an issue with updates because you tried to install older windows, use the Reset function (in Windows Updates) to restore to factory condition and then let updates work.

Comment: So, the machine updates itself but fails to do so ? Cause I waited like 3 hours and nothing happened. Also, why did it work once ?

Comment: Because Windows always updates itself.  Worked once was more than likely timing of updates.  I amended my post because you probably should use the Reset function to start new.

Comment: Is there any way to solve the problem then, maybe just try again and hope there is no update ongoing ?

Comment: No not really.  Windows is designed to update and not go backwards or stand still

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by downloading another windows 10 1703 iso, not from rufus.

Worked twice, didn't try more.